# Will one piece of sod immediately die?

Tags: sod, yard

My dad doesn't want to plant new grass in the yard since he thinks it will die. He "challenged" me to grow one piece of sod, and if that succeeds, then try planting seeds.

I think it would die regardless of what you do. Is there something you can do to make it grow?

Comment: If you have sun, you can grow grass. It is high maintenance though.

Comment: even from just one piece of sod?

Comment: @eliasciur Yes, even from just one piece of sod. You see grasses are invasive and propagate themselves from roots, runners and seeds. Some even root from the hedge trimmings. So it all ends down upon what type of grass it is, how early you want them to show visible results and in what proportion do you want them to grow

Comment: @Jayparth Doesn't that somewhat depend on the type of grass.  I know Kikuyu lawn is more-or-less a weed here - and almost impossible to kill without chemicals - but I understand grasses like Fescue and Rygrass don't use rhyzomes, so they won't spread so quickly.

Comment: @ellasciur what country/city are you in (or what is your hardiness zone?).  Do you know what kin of grass?     Different grasses are suitable to different climates.  Your dads thinking has merit - if conditions are OK you should be able to support a small piece of sod - especially if you have it in the ground where you plan on planting it.

Comment: What is the current condition of the yard? Have you made a soil test? Some locations your best bet for grass is artificial, or you waste a lot of resources making grass grow in an unsuitable climate...

Comment: @davidgo Yeah! You are right it does depends on the type of grass here. But unless it GMO or modified to be sterile they can still spread pretty fast from seeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether its one piece of sod or grass seed, it will grow the same and requires the same conditions.  Which are

- sunshine
- reasonable soil
- reasonable temperature
- reasonable moisture

Plant it in spring, and water it every two days, daily in summer.  Best to do it in the morning or evening.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if it's one piece of sod or an entire yard of sod or seed - if conditions are suitable, it will grow, if not, it will die. So on that basis your dad's "test" is quite reasonable.

Of course, if you just plunk down a piece of sod and don't care for it, it may well die. And if the conditions are not suitable for it, it may well die. Whether it's reasonable to grow grass in your location and on the soils you have is unknown as you have not shared any details.

Comment: @I wish Kikuyu would die if neglected.  Instead it spreads like wildfire.